# How to pass arguments to script in yarn 2 (berry)

Tags: command-line, parameter-passing, upgrade, yarnpkg

I have a simple script e.g.

```
# my-script.sh
echo "output: $1"
```

in my package.json I have a script to easily call this script:

```
"scripts": {
   "output-it": "bash my-script.sh $1"
}
```

In yarn 1 it just could call `yarn output-it 'hello world'` which worked fine. Now after updating to yarn 2 / berry / modern, I get an error `Unbound argument #1`

I checked the docs:
yarn 1 mentioned the option for [passing arguments](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run/#toc-yarn-run-script) `yarn run [script] [<args>]`
in yarn 2 i cannot find an option for this: https://yarnpkg.com/cli/run

How can I pass a parameter when calling a yarn script?

Answer (score 0):

```json
"scripts": {
  "output-it": "bash my-script.sh \"$@\""
}
```

From: https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/manifest/#scripts